# What does the $R$ stand for in $R_\xi$ gauge?

Tags: specific-reference, gauge

The [$R_\xi$ gauge fixing condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#R.CE.BE_gauges) is a term that can be added to a Lagrangian to choose a certain gauge: 
$$
\delta\mathcal L = -\frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2
$$
Here, $\xi$ is the parameter that decides the gauge, but where does the $R$ come from?

Comment: Something for History of Science and Mathematics SE?

Comment: Huh, didn’t know this existed. I was relying on the specific-reference tag.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean by "come from". Is this a question about its historical origins, or something else? If the former, it should go to [hsm.se]; if the latter, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Basically this: Force is denoted by $F$, because “force” starts with an “f” $\to$ why do we use $R$ for the $R_\xi$ gauge?  — therefore I think it may be better to ask this on the other site, thank you for the hint!

Comment: ["*The name $R_\xi$ gauge has historically been used only in the context of spontaneous symmetry breaking — see section 85 — but we will use it here as well. $R$ stands for* renormalizable *and $\xi$ stands for $\xi$.*"](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html)

Comment: Case closed, thank you! (p.370 in the draft / p.377 in the published version for those wondering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comment by @[AccidentalFourierTransform](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/84967/accidentalfouriertransform), here are two references:

1. M. Srednicki, "Quantum Field Theory", 4th Edition, Chapter 62, page 377 (emphasis mine)

> Here we have used the freedom to add $k^\mu$ or $k^\nu$ terms to put the propagator into generalized Feynman gauge or $R_\xi$ gauge. (The name $R_\xi$ gauge has historically been used only in the context of spontaneous symmetry breaking – see section 85 – but we will use it here as well. $R$ stands for **renormalizable** and $\xi$ stands for $\xi$.)

$\phantom{x}$

2. M. E. Peskin, D. V. Schroeder, "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" (2018), Chapter 21, page 738 (emphasis mine)

> The gauges defined by the possible values of $\xi$ are known as the **renormalizability**, or $R_\xi$, gauges.